# Grunt change index.html reference

Tags: build, reference, gruntjs

When using grunt is it possible to alter the references within a html file.

For example as part of my build process I am altering the filename from style.css to style.min.css.

What I would like to do is within my index.html file alter the reference to the stylesheet to use the minified version.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, have a look at `grunt-usemin`. The README is pretty exhaustive. :)

https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin

Comment: +1, answer to a similar question that has an example of usemin: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19130830/557612

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution, which avoids defining block comments in your html markup, is to install the plugin named: [grunt-text-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-text-replace)

**installing the plugin via npm:**

`$ npm install grunt-text-replace --save-dev`

and then and add the following to your `Gruntfile`:

**Gruntfile.js:**

```js
grunt.initConfig({

    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    /* UPDATES CSS SRC REFERENCED IN YOUR THE HTML FILE */
    replace: {
        cssLink: {
            src: ['./src/index.html'], //<--- The path to your html file
            overwrite: true,
            replacements: [{
                // Subsitute src="css/ below with the path to your CSS file.
                from: 'src="css/style.css',
                // Subsitute src="css/ above with the path to your minified CSS file.
                to: 'src="css/style.min.css'
            }]
        }
    }

});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-text-replace');

grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'replace:cssLink'
]);
```

};